# Internet Explorer trouble

Tags: actionscript-2

i have done this quiz but is there problem with IE
shows flash movie in small - i dont know what is the problem
shows full size of image - its an problem

in Firefox,Chrome,Safari works fine

here is the site :

http://kviztest.ic.cz/index.html?lang=sk

Anyone who has some troubles with Internet Explorer?
thanks for replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem. in the HTML code you are missing " sign

> OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"\n'+
>
> ' codebase="...see source...\n **" <- Here you need to add it** '+
>
> ' WIDTH="700" HEIGHT="500"